# Issues with rendering arabic text on ios [React Native]

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native, expo, arabic

I am working on a react native app which requires me to render Arabic styled text (The one found in the Holy Quran). the text renders perfectly on android but causes text to overlap or display incorrectly on iOS build. Tried different fonts double checked the text strings from the database but nothing seems to help on ios version. [See how  ط cuts through the word and ج doesn't fit properly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mOlj9.jpg). any help is appreciated.

I've tried the following.

- changing different fonts
- double checking text strings coming from database
- different text sizing and spacings.